# How can i make bootstrap dropdown menu to open/expand upwards instead of downwards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

Here's my HTML code and it has default bootstrap CSS, which expands/opens dropdown options downwards.

```
  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
     <label>{{'crm.crmpopup.newCustomer.cardType'|translate}}:</label>
     <div class="input-row">
        <select class="form-control" chosen name="cardType" ng-model="pageData.customer.cardType">
           <option value="Visa">{{'crm.crmpopup.newCustomer.visa'|translate}}</option>
           <option value="MasterCard">{{'crm.crmpopup.newCustomer.masterCard'|translate}}</option>
           <option value="AmericanExpress">{{'crm.crmpopup.newCustomer.americanExpress'|translate}}</option>
           <option value="DinersClub">{{'crm.crmpopup.newCustomer.dinersClub'|translate}}</option>
           <option value="Discover">{{'crm.crmpopup.newCustomer.discover'|translate}}</option>
           <option value="EnRoute">{{'crm.crmpopup.newCustomer.enRoute'|translate}}</option>
           <option value="JCB">{{'crm.crmpopup.newCustomer.jcb'|translate}}</option>
        </select>
     </div>
  </div>
```

How can i make bootstrap dropdown menu to open/expand upwards?

Comment: What do you mean of `open upward` ?

Comment: can you describe your problem in brief. and if possible with screenshot

Comment: I have a popup window in which i have the dropdown menu at the bottom of that popup window
so whenever it is selected the dropdown menu goes into the screen.
so every time i have to scroll down the window
i want to open that dropdown menu in the upward direction so that it is easily visible and then the screen would not be scrolled each time the dropdown menu is selected

Answer (score 2):

The default `select` HTML tag is limited in what it can do. You have to used a custom setup for this. The following Bootstrap code will create a dropdown going up instead of down.

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Dropup</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `dropup` class. This is what allows it to go up instead of down. You can view the [Bootstrap documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#dropup-variation) that refers to that [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#dropup-variation).

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it! If it helped you feel free to accept it if you believe it's the best answer. Glad it helped tho!!

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me :

```
<select class="selectpicker dropup" data-dropup-auto="false">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option></select>
```

Note: Applying the 'dropup' class only works if 'dropupAuto' is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a select menu. You need to get rid of it and use the bootstrap dropdown.

Use the following code:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Dropup</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful support..Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Below is working example that uses `Bootstrap 3.3.7`. [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropup class makes the dropdown menu expand upwards instead of downwards:</p>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="dropup">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropup Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```